# I am using react-spreadsheet in which I wrote code to to add a row dynamically ,but I am not getting how to highlight the added row

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i need to get that added row should be forcused.

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Spreadsheet } from 'react-spreadsheet';

const MySpreadsheet = () => {
const [focusedCell, setFocusedCell] = useState({ rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0 }); // representing the initial focused cell.
const [rowData, setRowData] = useState([
[{ value: '1',}, { value: '2' }, { value: '3' }, { value: '4' }, { value: '5' }, { value: '6' }],
[{ value: '7' }, { value: '8' }, { value: '9' }, { value: '0' }, { value: '1' }, { value: '2' }],
]);

```
const handleSelect = (rowIndex, columnIndex, selected) => {
    console.log('onSelect:');
 
    console.log('Cell:', rowIndex, columnIndex);
    setFocusedCell({ rowIndex, columnIndex });
};



const handleBlur = (rowIndex, columnIndex) => {
    console.log('Blur:');
    console.log("Blur celll", rowIndex, columnIndex);
};

const addRow = () => {
    const newRow = [{ value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }, { value: '' }]; 
    setRowData(prevRowData => [...prevRowData, newRow]);

  
    console.log("row value is",rowData[1][2]);
  

    console.log('setFocusedCell:', focusedCell);
};


useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Focused Here first time", focusedCell)
    setFocusedCell({ rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0 });
   
}, []);     


return (
    <>
        <div style={{ marginTop: '40px' }}>
            <button onClick={addRow}>Add Row</button>
        </div>
        <div style={{ marginTop: '40px' }}>
            <Spreadsheet
                data={rowData}
                onSelect={handleSelect}
                onBlur={handleBlur}
                focusedCell={focusedCell} // Pass the focusedCell state to the Spreadsheet component
            />
        </div>
    </>
);
```

};

export default MySpreadsheet;